# How to find trigger in system which is using two DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a trigger in SQL Server 2008 R2. I have used two database's tables in that trigger. I tried to find it in `Programmability -> Database Triggers` of both DB but I am not finding it out. Can anyone help me how to locate it? I have even forget its name (I have created weeks ago). Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will list all the triggers in your database, with the most recently created at the top of the list:

```
SELECT name,create_date 
FROM sys.triggers 
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

side note:

The trigger doesn't appear in `Programmability > Database Triggers` because this area contains triggers which are linked to the database (like DDL triggers). Standard triggers are attached to database tables and appear beneath the owning table in the `Tables` section of the SSMS tree - they aren't listed independently.

Comment: Why would you query `sys.objects` rather than `sys.triggers`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - thanks for that - I updated the answer to reflect your suggestion. However, to answer your question with another question - other than typing fewer characters, do you have reason to think it matters which of the views is accessed for this kind of query?